# How to replace elements in python list when performing sum() on list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, sum

I have a python list containing integers and string data types. All I need to do is to perform a replacement of the element when performing `sum()` function on the list.

For ex:
The list is `lis=[ 1, 4, 'Jan', 8]`, I need to replace `Jan` with integer `1` when performing  sum function on it. So the final output of sum function - `sum(lis)` becomes `1 + 4 + 1 + 8` which results to `14`.

There may be multiple such strings in the list and all those strings needs to be replaced when performing `sum()` on list. Suppose `Feb=2, Mar=3, Apr=4`, `Feb` replaced by `2` when `sum()` is called etc.

I don't want the elements in the list to be replaced. They should be replaced only when the sum is called. Is there any inbuilt function or something to do that?

Comment: No, there is no inbuilt function to do precisely what you are looking for. You will need to tie together a couple of things i.e. a dictionary converting months to numbers. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah. I tried that. Just looking for if there is any inbuilt function to do the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to *map* the elements of your list to values during summation. You will need to create a function that does that (there could not be a built-in one for that, only you know the values). Something like

```
def f(value):
   if isinstance(value, int):
      return value
   return months[value]
```

where `months` is a dict like `{'jan': 1, 'feb': 2...}`

Then

```
sum([f(value) for value in my_list])
```

or

```
sum(map(f, my_list))
```

Comment: `sum([months.get(i) or i for i in lis])` if integers won't be keys in the dictionary.

Comment: @user3483203: interesting approach, though a bit harder to read

Comment: @user3483203 why not `sum([months.get(i, i) for i in lis])`?

Comment: @roganjosh: hahaha, this is getting good, we should make a list

Comment: @blue_note we did. In fact, we made a whole list comprehension :) But I'd argue that my approach is the most pythonic since you can pass a default value to `.get()` in the case of a failed dict lookup. In this case, I don't see the need for the custom function. Don't bother checking the type, just see whether it exists in the dict or not.

Comment: @roganjosh: it is indeed the most pythonic. though, if I was going through that code, I'd need to read it twice to be sure what it does. Still, in terms of pythonic-ness, it wins

Comment: If it isn't readable it isn't Pythonic, but I disagree that it isn't readable

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary that maps months to month number and then a list comprehension as follows

```
months = { 'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, 'Apr': 4, 'May': 5
          'Jun': 6, 'Jul': 7, 'Aug': 8, 'Sep':9, 'Oct':10
          'Nov':11, 'Dec':12 }
sum([months[x] if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in lis])
```